# Activating a defined macro in a class from main.cpp

Tags: c++, atmega2560

Sorry if this question been asked. I'm trying to activate certain function in a class using a macro defined in the class from main.cpp. I'm using jrowberg MPU6050 library if that matters.

main.cpp

```
#include "gyro.h"
gyro gyro(Serial);
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER

void setup(){
...
}
void loop(){
...
}
```

gyro.cpp

```
  #include "gyro.h"
  #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
      // display Euler angles in degrees
      mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
      mpu.dmpGetEuler(euler, &q);
      serial_.print("euler\t");
      serial_.print(euler[0] * 180/M_PI);
      serial_.print("\t");
      serial_.print(euler[1] * 180/M_PI);
      serial_.print("\t");
      serial_.println(euler[2] * 180/M_PI);
  #endif
```

If I define `OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER` in `gyro.h`, it works. But I want to do it from main.cpp.

Comment: Try putting the define before you include the file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot not, but also you should not try to define a macro in a cpp file and use it in another cpp file.

Instead, you have to define it in a h (header) file, which is included in both cpp files.

Why would you define it in `main.cpp` or `main.h` anyway if you don't use it in those files?

You have mainly three options:

- Define it in `gyro.h` so you include it in `gyro.cpp` where you use it. You can later use it in other files as well.
- Define it in `gyro.cpp` so you can use it only in that file. This prevents the macro being used in other files (which can be safer).
- Define it in a separate file, e.g. `euler.h` and include this header file everywhere you need it.

See also Juraj's comments below.

Comment: this applies if the define should by in a source file. this kind of defines is usually set on compiler command line as -D. the Arduino IDE doesn't have -D define configuration for a project.

Comment: @Juraj in that case it could be an option to create a specific header file with those macros (one in this case) and include them in every file.

Comment: yes. it is the way if the macro should be used only in the sketch's files (project). inconvenient is it for libraries. then the user must go to library folder and a modifiy a file there, but then it applies for all projects. if the setting is boards specific or one has a customized board definition for a project, then -D can be set in boards.local.txt as build.extra_flags. for example in Eclipse -D can be set in project's settings

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for that additional info. However, that doesn't work in the IDE I guess ?(as the Arduino IDE is not eclipse based)